# Special character not encoding Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8, ascii, special-characters

I am trying to concatenate multiple fields together using Pandas. I have done this successfully before. My issue is between two columns I need to insert a ' à ' special character. No matter what I tried this character always turns into a question mark once its exported to csv.

I have tried opening in excel and notepad++, both do the same no matter what I tell the program the encoding is.

The kicker is there is other special characters in my data set and in my script but they have behaved properly.

I have tried:

- encoding the special character specifically to utf-8
- Turning it into a variable and then encoding it to utf-8
- encoding the csv when it originally is opened in pandas
- encoding the csv when it is written to a new file upon export
- populating a column with only the special
  character and concatenating it with the rest of the values

What I want is this:

401 À 403 RUE THOMAS LACHUTE QUEBEC J8H 4N7

What I get is this:

401 ? 403 RUE THOMAS LACHUTE QUEBEC J8H 4N7

```
dfFromCRM.loc[((dfFromCRM['Province']=='QUEBEC') & (dfFromCRM['Street Number From']!=0), 
['Address'])]= dfFromCRM['Street Number From'].map(str)  + 'à' +  concatonateQuebec
```

Comment: Could you please post code that can be run? (both to get the data and how you're saving the CSV?) It looks like some of you code was cut off.

Comment: whoops sorry, its correct now.

Answer (score -1):

If you are converting the dataframe to csv, then use utf-8-sig as encoding. It may work
dataframe.to_csv(filepath,encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)